# Transform a string into an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm searching the shortest method to transform a string like

```
"str1,str2,str3,..."
```

into an array of arrays like :

```
[["str1"], ["str2"], ["str3"]]
```

I could use a loop or an each, but I wonder if there is something more elegant.

Comment: Do you definately each of those string in an array inside an array that has nothing else in it or did you really mean `["str1", "str2", str3"]`?

Comment: I really need to get an array of arrays.

Comment: fair enough, just checking it wasn't a misunderstanding of syntax that would yeald answers you didn't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `split()` and `map()` like so:

```
// This could be turned into 1 line but is split here for readibility 
var array = string.split(',');

array = array.map(function(value){
    return [value];
});
```

**Note:** `map()` doesn't exist in all implementations, check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info on it.

Comment: Argg, I'm screwed, I must support IE7.
But thanks, it would be a fine solution for me.

Comment: Gotta love IE keeping you on your toes! But that article details how to implement it yourself so all is not lost!

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting an ES5 supporting browser you could use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var array = "str1,str2,str3".split(",").map(function(token) {
     return [token]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tom Walter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297721/546661) is great, but in case you don't want to use `map`:

```
var str = "str1,str2,str3";
var arr = str.split(",");
var arrOfarrs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arrOfarrs.push([arr[i]]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a `map` polyfill to add support for older browsers:

```
Array.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map || function(fn) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    arr.push(fn(this[i]));
  }
  return arr;
};
```

which would then allow you to do

```
var arr = str.split(",").map(function(val) {
  return [val];
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's more or less the solution I adopted (I'm using the Extjs "Ext.each()" method since I use this framework)